# How to disable blinking of textview onClick

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` with an `onClickListener()`.
When I click on the `TextView` it blinks.
How to disable this effect?

Here is the XML

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:maxLines="3"
                />
```

I tried to remove `android:ellipsize` and `android:maxLines` tags - no effect.

And here is the code:

```
accountDescriptionTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);

        accountDescriptionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (descriptionOpened)
            {
            //  accountDescriptionTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            //  accountDescriptionTextView.setMaxLines(3);
                descriptionOpened = false;
            }
            else
            {
            //  accountDescriptionTextView.setEllipsize(null);
            //  accountDescriptionTextView.setMaxLines(100);
                descriptionOpened = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

I need to have the commented functionality, but even when this lines are commented I still see how the textview blinks.

The text just disapears when i place my finger on the screen and apears when I take the finger away.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. Show us some code.

Comment: can you post your code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android uses a selector to give different colors to widgets' pressed state.

If you don't want that behavior, you can use solid colors for `android:textColor` and `android:textColorHighlight`.

Check the [TextView doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).